# Process Migration Scripting

Tags: linux, process, migration

I want to write some shell script which can perform the process migration from one node to another. Is it possible ? Can somebody please help me scripting this.

What all should I know before coding it?

Comment: Nodes of what? A cluster installation may provide some migration mechanism, but of a whole VM, not of a single process. Is this a particular program or a general case?

Comment: @Gilles: A general case...it can be node of any application.

Answer (score 2):

You can't migrate a process from node to node in Linux without extending the system - it simply isn't supported by default.

The two tools that make this more practical than otherwise are:

- https://ftg.lbl.gov/projects/CheckpointRestart/
- http://wiki.openvz.org/Checkpointing_and_live_migration

Neither of those is simple, however, and they are not without substantial caveats.